# How to send data from node.js to index.html file, and display it?

Tags: html, node.js

**I have a problem, to display the data from node.js in index.html.**
I am trying to display the data, I got from MySQL database, which is working, but I don`t know what should I do next, to display it in index.html. Here is my node.js code:

```
const express = require("express");
const mysql = require('mysql2');
const app = express();

const connection = mysql.createConnection({
  host: 'localhost',
  user: 'root',
  password: 'somePassword',
  database: 'someDatabase'
});


app.get('/', (req, res) => {
      connection.query('SELECT * FROM someTable', (error, results, fields) => {
        if (error) {
          console.error(error);
          res.status(500).send('An error occurred');
        } else {
          const tableRows = results.map(result => {
            return `<div class="search_product"><h5 class="product_title">${result.name}</h5><p class="product_description">${result.price}</p><p class="product_price">${result.brand}</p></div>`;
          });
          const tableHtml = `${tableRows.join('')}`;
          res.send(tableHtml)
        }
      });
});




app.listen(3000, () => {
  console.log("Server is running on port 3000");
});
```

I thought I found the way in internet to do it, but that was something about how to display the data from index.html in node.js / directory

Comment: Either index.html uses client-side js to call your server-side js or you need to get rid of index.html and generate the html right out of your server-side js.

Comment: I underdtand that nodejs is a server-side, but if I insert in nodejs html, then on the page the css and images aren`t showing, and that is a problem. The problem is not with pathes

Comment: Then you asked the wrong question. Please go and edit youe question adding your real problem.

Answer (score 1):

As Shadow said, you will need to have your HTML connected to some client-side JS using the `fetch` API to get the response from your server-side node.js code. Inside your client-side JS, add this code:

```js
let tableDiv = docuemnt.getElementByID('table');

let fetchTable = function() {
    fetch(`/`).then(function(response) {
        response
            .json()
            .then(function(data) {
            // Use the HTML from your node.js and add it to your HTML file
                tableDiv.innerHTML = data; // This is assuming that your data is html
            })
            .catch(function(error) {
                console.log(`There has been an error: \n ${error}`);
            });
      });
}

fetchTable();
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch